# Rails RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, routes

I'm creating a rest api using rails and making calls from a remote ember app using ember data. I'm getting this routing error on what should be a GET request. How do I create an OPTIONS method and will I have to do this for every resource?

I can provide code snippets if needed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Installing and configuring this gem should allow your Rails application to properly process the options request caused by CORS:

https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors

Comment: I figured this out 10 minutes after I posted the question. Thanks

Comment: Of all my attempts this was the one that worked. Thanks!