# Facebook Auth / CORS preflight and Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I'm implementing a facebook authentication with client side flow.
After that, I'd like to integrate with the Omniauth framework on backend using the cookies strategy.
The problem is that after login on facebook and try to call the Omniauth callback, on the preflight requisition (`OPTIONS`), my global option route is not recognized and the backend doesn't return any CORS headers.

Route definition:

```
  match '*path', to: 'application#handle_options_request', constraints: {:method => 'OPTIONS'}
```

When calling the callback, it never passes on `application#handle_options_request`:

```
[2014-09-02 18:02:25] INFO  Rails : Started OPTIONS "/users/auth/facebook" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-02 18:02:25 +0100
```

All the others `OPTION` request based are routed fine but not this one above.
Has anyone already faced this problem?

====

Omniauth routes

```
$ bundle exec rake routes

  user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)        authentications#passthru {:provider=>/facebook|google_oauth2|twitter/}
  user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)  authentications#(?-mix:facebook|google_oauth2|twitter)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588699/rails-routingerror-no-route-matches-options ?

Comment: I'm going to test it but anyway, is there any reason for I get that OPTIONS request not reaching the route I want?

Comment: Not sure, sorry - I've just seen a rash of these lately, and that seemed the most relevant...