# Ember not sending a DELETE on destroyRecord()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Having issues getting the activeModelAdapter to send a DELETE request on .destroyRecord, I also tried .deleteRecord with .save(), but get the same results....

I already have installed the rack-cors gem, so my api is already excepting cross-origin requests

**ERROR:**

> Started OPTIONS "/brands/117" for ::1 at 2015-04-20 17:51:05 -0700> 
>   ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS]
>   "/brands/117"):

**BRANDS CONTROLLER:**

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     needs: 'application',
     currentUser: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.currentUser'),
     currentPath: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.currentPath'),
     actions: {
        deleteBrand: function(brand) {
           brand.destroyRecord();
        }
     },
     showButton: function() {
        return this.currentPath === 'brands';
     }.property('controllers.application.currentPath')
});
```

**BRANDS TEMPLATE:**

```
<h2>Brands</h2>

{{#if showButton}}
    {{#link-to 'brands.new' class="bam-btn submit login" tagName="button"}}Create A Brand{{/link-to}}
{{/if}}

{{outlet}}

{{search-brands}}

{{!-- LIST OF BRANDS --}}

<h2 class="bam-clear">List of {{ controllers.application.currentUser }} brands</h2>

<ul>
    {{#each brand in model}}
        {{#link-to 'brand.dashboard' brand.slug}}
         <li><h3>{{brand.brand_name}}</h3></li>
         <button id="deleteBrand" class="bam-btn alert" {{action 'deleteBrand' brand}}>Delete</button>
         {{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
 </ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails RoutingError (No route matches \[OPTIONS\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588699/rails-routingerror-no-route-matches-options)

Comment: ehhhhhhh, an action inside an anchor tag is problematic, similar to having anchor tags inside of anchor tags

Comment: No, I have installed the cors gem already..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to included the :delete method in my RACK::Cors config.

*config/application.rb:*

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :delete, :options]
  end
end
```